# Attempt to read property "id" on null - description.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have a problem with id
i get error

> Attempt to read property "id" on null (View: /resources/views/admin/Attendance/description.blade.php)

view code that show error

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('time.outd',['id'=>$attend->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

controller code:

```
 public function outd(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'out'=>'',
        'description'=>'required',
    ]);
    $attend=Attendance::where('employee_id',$id)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
    $attend->description=$request->get('description');
    $attend->update([
        'out' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
    $attend->save();
    return redirect()->route('time.index')->with('success', ' success.');
}
```

Comment: `$attend` is `null`. Where do you set it/pass it to the view?

Comment: @brombeer how to set it?

Comment: where are you rendering the blade view admin/Attendance/description.blade.php ?

Comment: By reading the documentation on [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just a little off here. `'$attend->id` you are setting the id to a null value because you haven't set it.  From the controller that is passing the view of this form you need to pass that id to the front. So your collection of $attend is available on the front. Should be something like this in your controller action.

```
return view('index', compact('attend'));
```

Then in your form action just post to a non wildcard route...

```
action="{{route('time.outd')}}"
```

Then in your form elements put...

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$attend->id}}">
```

Then in your controller where this is being posted to your id will be...

```
$request->id
```

Now you know if it is null on the back-end post that there was no record from the model and that you need to create a new one. If it has an id then you can go on about your day processing.